# Combining Different Scaled arrays in dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

Is there a built-in function (numpy or pandas I'm thinking) that would help combine multiple rows of one column in a dataframe, keeping the same dimensions, but different scale?  Also, combined with that, summing the values from a different column between the intervals?  Or is it something I just need to build from scratch?  Example below, I'm not sure exactly how to ask.  This would need to be scalable; the example is simple, in reality I'm working with a 250 dim array and theoretically unlimited rows.

Ex:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

#Creating DF

df = pd.DataFrame([[[-2,-1,0,1,2],[-10,-5,5,5,-10]],
                   [[-.5,.5,1.5,2.5,3.5],[-3,-2,0,-2,-3]]])



output:                     0                     1
    0           [-2, -1, 0, 1, 2]  [-10, -5, 5, 5, -10]
    1  [-0.5, 0.5, 1.5, 2.5, 3.5]   [-3, -2, 0, -2, -3]
```

where the answer is [-2,-0.625,0.75,2.125,3.5] (column0 combined with dim 5) , [-10,-5,0,-5,-5] (sum of column1 between steps of column0 where (interval-1) < x<=interval)

```
answer = pd.DataFrame([[[-2,-.625,.75,2.125,3.5],[-10,-5,0,-5,-5]]])
```

Comment: It's very unclear what you're asking. How do you reach these outputs from these inputs?

Comment: column1 is based on stock options pricing from stock prices (column0) and in actuality column0 is the standard deviation from current price.

Comment: I should clarify... I can figure out column 0 as x = np.linspace(min(min(df.iloc[:,0])),max(max(df.iloc[:,0])), 5) with 5 intervals.  I need help summing the column 1 values that correspond to between the interval values.

Comment: conceptually each row is a paired value so if in a dictionary it would be row0 = { -2:-10 , -1:-5 , 0:5 , 1:5 , 2:-10} and row1 = {-.5:-3, .5:-2, 1.5:0, 2.5:-2, 3.5:-3}.  Somehow I need to iterate through each row and sum each value between the intervals of new x linspace (min,max)

Comment: I'm sorry, maybe I'm being dense, but how do you get from ` -2:-10 , -1:-5 , 0:5 , 1:5 , 2:-10` to `-10,-5,0,-5,-5`? If you could show some pseudocode for the algorithm to get to the answer that would really help my brain

Comment: using x and y for simplicity: column0=x, column1=y.  the first part I have figured out, as above, the answer x = linspace(min(x),max(x), num of intervals).  The ys are the trouble.  have to start somewhere, so similar to merge(left) let's say y[0] = sum of all ys where x=-2, or -10.  Then y[1] = (sum of all ys where -2< x <= -.625) which is sum(x=-1: -5) so [-10, -5 ...] y[2] is then (sum of all ys where -.625 < x <= .75) or sum(x=-.5: -3, x=0: 5, x=.5: -2) = 0...y[2]=0.  y[3] is then (sum of all ys where .75 < x <=2.125) or sum(x=1: 5,  x=1.5:0, x=2:-10) = -5 and finally

Comment: y[4] = (sum all of ys where 2.125 < x <= 3.5) or sum(x=2.5: -2, x=3.5: -3) = -5... so answer y = [-10,-5,0,-5,-5]

Comment: So given your original question, I think the answer is no, there isn't something built-in for your purpose. Your best bet may be to write the customer function, then you `apply()` to apply it to the rows of your DF. If your DF is going to be very large, I would look into some optimization options outlined in the [enhancing performance](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/enhancingperf.html) docs